# How can I see file by file update in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play-services, delta, app-update

Good day, Everyone!

As I know, Google use File-by-File patching technology (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html) and Delta-patching to reduce APK update size. But, right now, on testing step, it doesn't seems to be applied to my application.

I have an app in Play Store in Closed Testing. Audience is not to big (3-5 accounts).
How can I test/reproduce File-by-File patching technology?
Do you know conditions, when Google starts use this technology for my app?
Does it depends on downloads count, accounts count, timeframe?
Is it in general possible to see this feature work during testing?
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it doesn't seem that they mention anything about the testing environment. This is something for apps that are continuously being updated, say every 2-4 weeks or even every 2-4 months. However, please look at this [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/tracking-app-update-sizes-1a1f57634f7b) it might be of use to you.